# Renaming files to add a suffix

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I need a command to rename all files in the current working directory, in a way that the new filename will be the same as the old, but including a suffix corresponding to the number of lines of the original files (e.g. if the file `f` has 10 lines then it should be renamed to `f_10`).

Here's my (non-working) attempt:

```
 linenum=$(wc -l); find * -type f | grep -v sh | rename 's/^/ec/'*
```

Comment: You could make that an answer! (If it adds something new to the existing answers - but it looks like it does)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f"_$(wc -l < "$f"); done
```

For example:

```
$ wc -l *
 10 file1
 40 file2
100 file3
$ ls
file1_10  file2_40  file3_100
```

If you want to keep extensions (if present), use this instead:

```
for f in *; do 
    ext=""; 
    [[ $f =~ \. ]] && ext="."${f#*.}; 
    mv "$f" "${f%%.*}"_$(wc -l < "$f")$ext; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks terdon! this command line seems to get the work done but how can I change the dot (.) to( _)? Also, as my script is inside the folder, it is renamed too and hence allows my script to be executed once (because script name changes...)

Comment: @MartinYeboah see updated answer for the `_`. As for the script, what script? That should be run from the command line, there's no need for a script. If you only want it to match some files, change the `in *` to, for example, `in *txt` or something.

Comment: thanks a lot ;) I totally forgot that it should be executed from the command line :)

Comment: I think `wc -l < $f` instead of the grep would be easier to understand (and maybe better to perform but I haven't checked that).

Comment: @musiKk yes, but since the other answers are using `wc`, I wanted to show a different approach. But OK, fair enough.

Comment: @terdon Oh, I see. Didn't look too closely at the other answers. This is the accepted one most people will see so refining it makes the most sense in my book. Cheers! :)

Comment: @musiKk I don't know about you but "wc -l < $f" doesn't rename the files with "_"

Answer (score 10):

You can try this one liner:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -i "$1" "$1.$(wc -l <"$1")"' _ {} \;
```

- This will find all files in the current working directory (`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`)
- Then we are running a shell instance over the files found to rename the files to append the number of lines.

**Example :**

```
$ ls
bar.txt spam.txt foo.txt

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -i "$1" "$1.$(wc -l <"$1")"' _ {} \;

$ ls
bar.txt.12 foo.txt.24 spam.txt.7
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way which preserves the extension (if present) using `rename`:

```
for f in *; do rename -n "s/([^.]+)(\.?.*)/\$1_$(< "$f" wc -l)\$2/" "$f"; done
```

If the result is the expected one, remove the `-n` option:

```
for f in *; do rename "s/([^.]+)(\.?.*)/\$1_$(< "$f" wc -l)\$2/" "$f"; done
```

Comment: `rename` great =) +1

Comment: Wouldn't this fail on a.b.c.d? Change the second capture group to `(\.?[^\.]+)`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 That's true, however `(\.?[^\.]+)` is not ok either because it will match only up to the second dot and won't match a filename with consecutive dots or ending with a dot regardless. It's not an easy solution tough, the only way seems to do two substitutions.

Comment: @kos you are correct. How about ([^\.]+).*?([^\.]+$) I am not sure about optimality. Working fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/rQ9lX1/1

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Doesn't match a filename ending with a `.`, also the problem is that `.*?` even if grouped includes the last `.`, but the count of the lines should be inserted before it. That's not easy at all, i'm trying to grok this from at least an half an hour

Comment: Well,  this (https://regex101.com/r/qT5tM3/1) is matching even those cases. Hope this works out! You can add a `.` separately while replacing. I am writing the regex keeping in mind the capture group values.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 you don't want to escape `.` inside character classes.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Thanks for your effort, however thinking about this twice I don't think it's a good thing to rename files that way: think of a (say) `.tar.gz` extension. Dots after all are a consolidated way of separating a filename from its extension, so unless within particular scopes and hence the for the most common use, I think the best way to add stuffs would be to add them before the first dot (consider also that sometimes a missing extension breaks the program using the file).

Answer (score 5):

Using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do mv "$f" "$f"_$(grep -c . "$f"); done
```

---

*Example*

```
% wc -l *
  3 doit
  5 foo

% find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do mv "$f" "$f"_$(grep -c . "$f"); done

% wc -l *                         
  3 doit_3
  5 foo_5
```

Comment: Why the `-name "*"`? Leftover from tests? ;)

Comment: @kos Old habit :\

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun and giggles a solution with `rename`. Since `rename` is a Perl tool that accepts an arbitrary string that is eval'd, you can do all sorts of shenanigans. A solution that seems to work is the following:

```
rename 's/.*/open(my $f, "<", $_);my $c=()=<$f>;$_."_".$c/e' *
```

Comment: Interesting idea +1

Answer (score 2):

The script bellow covers multiple cases: the single dot and extension (file.txt), multiple dots and extensions(file.1.txt), consecutive dots (file..foobar.txt), and dots in the filename (file. or file..).

**The Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date:  June 25,2015
# Description: script to rename files to file_numlines
# written for http://askubuntu.com/q/640430/295286

# Where are the files ?
WORKINGDIR=/home/xieerqi/substitutions
# Where do you want them to go ?
OUTPUTDIR=/home/xieerqi/substitutions/output

for file in $WORKINGDIR/* ;do 
    FLAG=0
    EXT=$(printf "%s" "$file" | awk -F'.' '{printf "%s",$NF }' )  # extension, last field of dot-separated string
    # EXT="${file##*.}" # Helio's advice is to use parameter expansion, but I dont know how to use it
    if [ -z $EXT ]; then # we have a dot at the end case file. or something
        # so we gotta change extension and filename
        EXT=""
        FILENAME=$(printf "%s" "$file" | awk -F '/' '{ print $NF}' )
        # set flag for deciding how to rename
        FLAG=1
    else
        FILENAME=$( printf "%s" "$file" | awk -F '/' -v var=$EXT '{gsub("."var,"");print $NF}'   ) # filename, without path, lst in
    fi

    NUMLINES=$(wc -l "$file" | awk '{print $1}') # line count

    if [ $FLAG -eq 0 ];then
         echo "$file" renamed as "$OUTPUTDIR"/"$FILENAME"_"$NUMLINES"."$EXT"
        # cp "$file" "$OUTPUTDIR"/"$FILENAME"_"$NUMLINES"."$EXT" # uncomment when necessary
    else
        echo "$file" renamed as "$OUTPUTDIR"/"$FILENAME"_"$NUMLINES""$EXT"
        # cp "$file" "$OUTPUTDIR"/"$FILENAME"_"$NUMLINES""$EXT" # uncomment when necessary
    fi

    #printf "\n"

done
```

**Script in action**

```
$./renamer.sh                                                                                                           
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file. renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file._0
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.. renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.._0
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.1.jpg renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.1_3.jpg
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.1.test.jpg renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.1.test_3.jpg
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.1.test.txt renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.1.test_2.txt
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.1.txt renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.1_2.txt
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.2.jpg renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.2_3.jpg
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.2.test.jpg renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.2.test_3.jpg
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.2.test.txt renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.2.test_2.txt
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/file.2.txt renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/file.2_2.txt
/home/xieerqi/substitutions/foo..bar.txt renamed as /home/xieerqi/substitutions/output/foo..bar_4.txt
```

Note that there is no lines in file. and file.. , hence line count is 0

*Special thanks to terdon and Helio for reviewing the script and suggested edits*

Answer (score 2):

Another bash way, developed with [@Helio in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22388206#22388206):

```
for file in *
do
    echo "$file"
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
    [[ $file =~ (.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]
    cp "$file" "output/${BASH_REMATCH[1]:-$file}_$(wc -l < "$file")${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

The weird looking monocled guy with a stunted second head (`(.*)(\.[^.]+)$`) should match only proper extensions (`.foo`, not `..`). If there's no extension, then the `BASH_REMATCH` array will be empty. We can take advantage of this by using a default value for the filename `${BASH_REMATCH[1]:-$file}`, and just using the extension as is.

To handle dot files, you could use `find`, as suggested by [terdon and Helio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22400253#22400253).

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%P\0' | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    [[ $file =~ (.*)(\.[^.]+)$ ]]
    cp "$file" "output/${BASH_REMATCH[1]:-$file}_$(wc -l < "$file")${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

Comment: +1: I wouldn't be able to do a explaination for the command. **;-)**